# write umlaut with javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, web

I have this in my header

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and this in my htaccess:

```
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .css .js .xml .json .rss .atom
```

My browser is google chrome.
When i use a javascript variable as output in the html a 'ä' becomes 'Ã¤' ?

Comment: Please show more details about what goes wrong when

Comment: Please check encoding file with umlauts.

Comment: Check in your google chrome settings from top right, select `tools-> encoding` and see if it's set to utf-8 when viewing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set the correct charset in `<script>` tag that includes your file or encode all symbols outside of plain ASCII range as unicode entities - \xNNNN and thus make file charset-neutral. Some minifiers, like Google Closure Compiler, can do this for you.

Comment: like this `<script type="text/javascript">` ?

Comment: `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: has unfortunately no effect for me

Comment: Of course you should write correct encoding of your file, not just copy/paste "utf-8" from this example. Some comments on other answers suggest that you actually have ISO-8859-1 instead.

Comment: i switched everything to ISO-8859-1, now a ä is this ÃƒÂ¤

Comment: Well just use entity \x00E4 then and forget about encoding problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also save the document as UTF-8? If you are using Notepad++, try to change the coding of the document, save and refresh site.

Comment: i use aptana studio and in the preferences general/workspace/text file encoding UTF-8 is selected, i think that should be it shouldn't it ?

Comment: @user1011185 `"Ã¤"` are the bytes (`0xC3A4`) of utf8 encoded "ä" in encodings like ISO-8859-1, please check your encoding in tools->encoding in chrome